# PHP - regex/function to replace the nth ocurrence of a character within a string

Tags: php, regex, string, function, substitution

I have a SQL query string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE `manufacturer_id` = ? AND `date_added` < ?  `product_id` IN (?) AND `price` > ? ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;
```

This is handed over to a Query class constructor like this:

```
$query = new Query("SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE `manufacturer_id` = ? AND `date_added` < ?  `product_id` IN (?) AND `price` > ? ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;", 27, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), [17,18,29,30,46,47], 27.75);
```

I currently have a function which explodes the string with the question mark as the delimiter, count the number of marks and traverse the parameters, re-composing the query string so, for each parameter which is an array, I sustitute its question mark with as many question marks as parameters are in the array (so, instead of being `IN (?)` it gets corrected like `IN (?,?,?,?,?,?)`).

However, I don't like how my function looks like and would like to find a better equivalente or, if possible, a regex/function/SPL-driven procedure to make the substitution far easier than I have currently done.

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Why do you want to split your query? If you want to build a customized query. You might do better working top-down, instead of down-top. Just concatenate with the pre-defined strings. The definition of those strings can then go through an if-else/switch process to check for validity and integrity.

Comment: No, it can't go that way, as the constructor works like the `sprintf()` function, so I pass the query and then, all involved parameters, which are taken with the `func_get_args()` function. The idea is not to have any fixed/assumed condition, so I must process the query after it has been given, not before

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this;

```
$params = array(27, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), '[17,18,29,30,46,47]', 27.75);
$counter = 0;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE `manufacturer_id` = ? AND `date_added` < ?  `product_id` IN (?) AND `price` > ? ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;";

echo preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($matches) {
    $GLOBALS['counter']++;

    return $GLOBALS['params'][$GLOBALS['counter']-1];
}, $query);
```

**Output**

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE `manufacturer_id` = 27 AND `date_added` < 2013-04-08 10:29:43 `product_id` IN ([17,18,29,30,46,47]) AND `price` > 27.75 ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;
```

Not sure about the `IN ([17,18,29,30,46,47])` part, but you can modify the string to your liking in the `$params` array.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm that gave me an idea about using the `preg_replace_callback()` function. Thanks for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Just for the SQL query part but it's pretty fast and looks simple:

```
// takes ~1.25ms to complete (on average)
function str_replace_nth($haystack, $needle, $occurrence, $replacement) {
    $tmp = explode($needle, $haystack);

    if ($occurrence > sizeof($tmp)) {
        return $haystack;
    } else {
        $tmp[$occurrence - 1] .= "{$replacement}{$tmp[$occurrence]}";
        unset($tmp[$occurrence]);
        return implode($needle, $tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still... I feel like there could be a better alternative using regexes... any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, do you reckon you can make it clearer what the regex needs to do? e.g. do all the ? symbols need to be expanded out to the number of parameters? - will you actually have the number of parameters at hand?

Comment: I've added an answer with a callback and a global counter so you can do something different (replace) on each time the question-mark is matched.

Comment: I saw it, and it looks promising. Not copying the same code as passing `[1,2,3,4,5,...,n]` isn't what I look for. Given the number of parameters, I need to scan each question mark and check if its corresponding parameter is simple or multiple. If it's multiple, I need to re-adjust the question mark to put as many question marks as parameters are in the array being passed as parameter. If it's simple, no substitution is made. I'll slide an `if ()` inside the callback function and see how it goes. Like I said, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @d'alar'cop I always have the parameters at hand, as my constructor works (like I said) like the `sprintf()` function and, hence, I will always have both the query string and the parameters.

Comment: If you look at my example more thoroughly, you can see that you have absolute fine-grain control over each position a question-mark can be because of the counter-variable. You could alter the returned value to `return '';` if you want to skip a placeholding question-mark to not fill in a space. As far as the array (that I've put in a string-format) goes; you can just do a loop to build up a certain matching group that will exactly match the placeholders in the different queries you have. Shouldn't be that hard :)